# installing Nusmv on linux

Tags: model-checking, nusmv

I have searched in vain to see how to run NuSMV on ubuntu 16.04 .I have installed NuSMV binaries ,I have an executable NuSMV in bin folder but it won't run.I type `NuSMV -help` but cmd reports `NuSMV:command not found`.Any idea on how to run NuSMV/or is there anything like installation that I am missing?

Comment: just add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/directory/containing/the/NuSMV/binary` to your `.bashrc` file

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what a .bashrc file does.I find bash.bashrc and dot.bashrc on my computer, do you mean the former.

Comment: the file is `$HOME/.bashrc`; please consider reading some basic introduction to `unix/linux`, it would greatly help to get you started with the system and dealing with and other small issues :)

Comment: You can find `.bashrc` in your home directory, type `vi ~/.bashrc` and paste command given by the @PatrickTrentin, with little changes of course, at the end of that file

Comment: I have tried  add this to .bashrc `export PATH:=$PATH/home/sak/Desktop/LogicAssignment3/NuSMV-2.6.0-Linux/bin`(the path) and later ran `source ~./bashrc `,but I get an invalid identifier error.I am new to linux ,so sorry about that.

Comment: Also tried pointing it to the parent directory (removed `/bin`),but did not work either.I think I am missing something fbasic here.Would be grateful if someone helped.

Comment: Sorry missed a `:` .Working now.Thank You very much @PatrickTrentin @bladekp.